# use an android map v1 key with different computers

Tags: android, dictionary

I have an app with a map v1. i changed my computer and want to use the same key as before, because it s not possible to make a api key v1 request ! I want to know how to do to use that api key in the same project !!    thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that map v1 key is not generated using a debug keystore, and you have the keystore file which is used to create this api key then you can use the same key on other computers and the map will work perfectly after signing its apk with that keystore file.

But I suggest you to move to v2 api as this one is deprecated. Also v2 is proving rich functionality.

Comment: that's what i want. i have the keystore, how to sign a apk with the keystore file ?!

Comment: Just right click on your project from eclipse and select the export option. then select export android application and complete the following procedures

Comment: [Sign apk](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp) try this link for detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

Switch over to map v2.map v1 no longer key been maintained and exists.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the same certificate that you use to generate that Key. If you don't have this then you will need to get a new key which will have to be google maps version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just sign with the same keystore. However I would suggest using Google Maps V2.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Do a very simple thing if you are not yet accomplished with your task..
Copy your debug.keystore file from your computer and replace it on any machine wherever you want.

You can use your v1 generated key.. And if you want to continue using Google API v1 preserv your debug.keystore file.